# Visual Studio 2010 Make and Install Templates

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, templates, installation

I am using F# and i found that the available templates were a bit to sparse for my liking, and i want to make more. How would i go about doing that? also, how would i install these templates after I've made them?

Answer (score 27):

In Visual Studio's path you will find the default templates, these are a set of zip files that get expanded into the template cach.

They are stored in

- Item Templates - `%VSInstallDir%\Common7\IDE\ItemTemplates\`
- Project Templates - `%VSInstallDir%\Common7\IDE\ProjectTemplates\`

Extracting the {{.zip}} in question and recompressing with the modified contents will update the template. You can also copy these files to one of the respective template folders in `%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Visual Studio 2010`.

For information on building templates have a look at [Visual Studio Templates](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky%28VS.100%29.aspx) on MSDN.

You then need to tell VS to rebuild the cache.

1. Open a visual studio command line shell
2. Execute `devenv /installvstemplates`

You can also use the "Export Template..." wizard from the file menu, however the exported template loses original content such as `if` statements.

Comment: Forget about this, I realised I just realised I needed to start the console with admin rights... duh!

Comment: I run devenv /installvstemplates, then visual studio templates lost. I can just see 2-3 templates after an error message.

Comment: @DavutGürbüz, do you happen to have a permissions issue? Or is there something wrong with the ZIP files in the template source location? Remember too that the ZIP files must not contain a parent directory, i.e. the Class.zip must contain no directories but have the Class.cs file and other meta files. If you do have d directory structure inside the ZIP when expanding VS will not see the content and not show its template.

Comment: I re-execute the command. Then templates come back. I changed something in my template as a result of: $safeprojectname$ did write this "$safeprojectname$" in code so I used "$rootnamespace$" instead. What I changed is these.Beside this rootnamespace give me the full namespace, I just want projectnamespace. Anyway , I have my templates and I'm happy. Lets work a bit :)

Comment: It seems in Visual Studio 2013 all templates were moved to the user folder: c:\Users\<user>\My Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Templates\ProjectTemplates.

Comment: They got moved there? In prior versions you could place your own in that dir, but that's kinda cool. Still on 2010 myself :)

Answer (score 6):

I ran into problems with this and multiple custom templates.  Each template (e.g. vstemplate + cs file) should be in it's own zip file.  If you put several into the same zip it won't pick up any of them.

I also found that if you put them in:

`$My Documents$\Visual Studio 2010\Templates\ItemTemplates`

then you wont need run the command (devenv /installvstemplates) mentioned by Brett.  Presumably this is only when modifying the existing ones in the install folder.

Here's a sample that I use for knocking up NUnit tests:

Code file (with .cs/relevant extension):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;  
using System.Text;
using NUnit.Framework;

namespace $rootnamespace$
{
    [TestFixture, Category("issue")]
    public class $safeitemname$
    {
        [SetUp]
        public void Setup()
        {

        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {

        }
    }
}
```

Template file (with .vstemplate extension):

```xml
<VSTemplate Version="3.0.0" Type="Item"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005" >
  <TemplateData>
    <DefaultName>ATest.cs</DefaultName>
    <Name>NUnit test</Name>
    <Description>
        with [TestFixture] attribute set on class and one empty method 
        called Test that has [Test] attribute
    </Description>
    <ProjectType>CSharp</ProjectType>
    <SortOrder>10</SortOrder>
    <Icon>someIcon.ico</Icon>
  </TemplateData>
  <TemplateContent>
    <References />
    <ProjectItem SubType="Code" TargetFileName="$fileinputname$.cs"
                 ReplaceParameters="true">TheCodeFile.cs</ProjectItem>
  </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```

Comment: I can't get my custom templates to show up in the Add New Item dialog no matter what I do. I've followed every tutorial to the T. Does this not work in Visual Studio 2015? I've checked Options to make sure that it's pointing at the right location.

Answer (score 2):

I'd try http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185291.aspx - it seems like a good starting point, at least.

Answer (score 2):

I was missing SharePoint 2010 and MOSS 2007 templates in Visual Studio 2010 development tool after my SharePoint installation. I reinstalled VS and found they were available. It looks like during installation of SharePoint pre-requisites for some reason I missed those templates from getting installed.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the complete example implemented here: [Multi-Project Templates with Wizard: Visual Studio 2010 Sample](http://vsix.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install VS 2010 SDK (or VS 2010 SP1 SDK) which contains new project templates such as *Item Template* template and *Project Template* template (I don't know if there's version for earlier versions of VS and if these templates are only for C# or not).

Visual Studio 2010 SP1 SDK:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21835

Visual Studio 2010 SDK:
http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=2680