# How to refresh template caches in VS 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, templates, xna, xna-4.0

I need to refresh the caches for item templates in visual studio to remove some deleted templates, and I have tried to run:

```
devenv.exe /installvstemplates
devenv.exe /setup

devenv /installvstemplates
devenv /setup
```

and all have failed to remove the deleted templates from the list.

Edit:

I just tried to change one of the stock templates, and refresh it with each of the above commands. It stayed the same in the list and worked just the same when I used it.

Edit:

Just like the idiot I am, I didn't use the Visual Studio Command Line, I used cmd.exe
Now it works fine, if a little slowly.

Comment: Did you see this question in SO: "Visual Studio 2010 Make and Install Templates" (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984703/visual-studio-2010-make-and-install-templates)

Comment: I know how to make templates, I do it all the time, but visual studio won't update and show any changes to them.

Comment: Did you see the second answer (the one from @Brett-Ryan) in the link I have given above? It talks about the problem you have specified in your question.

Comment: Thanks alot, man this has bugged me for ages. If you post your comment as an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: I cannot take credit for pointing out the answer given by some one else! Glad I could be of help and thanks for saying it :)